# Understanding Java Concurrency with thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, runnable

I'm currently reading a java concurrency tutorial in http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html

I could not understand what following lines under "Subclass or Runnable?"

When having the Runnable's executed by a thread pool it is easy to queue up the Runnable instances until a thread from the pool is idle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the article points out they both "work", although in general, you should use `Runnable` (or if arguments/result are needed `Callable` with a `Future`) rather than subclassing `Thread`. As you noted, this is more flexible -  it separates what is executed from whom is executing it. Extending Thread unnecessarily couples these two concepts tightly together in the same instance, breaking the OO principle of [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Occasionally you'll have to implement executable code as a subclass of Thread when your hand is forced by the API. For example, Runtime.[addShutdownHook(Thread)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) requires that your code to be executed at shutdown is registered as a Thread instance. But if you're not dealing with one of these specific cases, then always use a `Runnable`.

Answer (score 0):

The author just wants to convey that according to him Runnables are easier to use with thread pools. A concept of a thread pool is that you can have a fixed number of threads (say 10) waiting to take jobs. If all 10 of them are busy running threads, the outstanding work can be queued, until one of those threads from the pool is free.

Comment: So, if we have fixed number of threads to take jobs, whats the difference between using Thread extended thread and Runnable implemented Threads.

Comment: check this : http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ExtendingThreadVsImplementingRunnable

Bottom line:
By implementing Runnable rather than extending Thread, you minimize the amount of code that you might have to change later if you decide to use an Executor.

Comment: and ofcorse, executors and all the new good stuff works with Runnables..... In my opinion, you shouldnt need to worry about threads for a simple, straight-forward application after J5

Answer (score 0):

Jenkov is highlighting, that choosing between Subclass or Runnable implementation is due to the preference if anything else.

He is referring to the [thread pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) as an example why runnable interface implementation is more flexible. I support his original hypothesis, but mainly because the Runnable object can subclass a class other than Thread.

I don't quite see, how building thread pools would be **that** more cumbersome with subclasses of threads with java native libraries ie.
[java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). I wish Jenkov would have provided an example...

Comment: The problem is that each `Thread` object in fact is a new Java thread (which most often corresponds to a native thread). The point of thread pools is to avoid creating new threads if not necessary, since this is quite costly.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkov goes further in his concurrency tutorial to describe fixed and cached thread pools using the ExecutorService factory methods. Take a look here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html. With the Java concurrency utilities that create these thread pools, using runnables is easier.